# Warning: count() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

Tags: php, arrays, count, element

How do I get count() to count all elements in a group of arrays?

```
$a[0] = 1;
$a[1] = 3;
$a[2] = 5;
$b[0] = 2;
$b[1] = 4;
$b[2] = 6;
$c[0] = 8;
$c[1] = 9;
$c[2] = 10;
$result = count($a, $b, $c);

echo $result;
```

Comment: The error is very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count()` expect one or two parameter, but you give it three.

You can use,

```
array_sum(array_map('count', [$a, $b, $c]));
```